# Order query after JOIN and AND

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, sql-order-by

I'm having issues ordering this query, I've tried:

```
$query .= " ORDER BY t.id DESC";
```

and it does not show anything. Any light?

---

```
$query = "SELECT t.name, t.id FROM #__k2_tags as t";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN #__k2_tags_xref tags_xref ON tags_xref.tagID = t.id";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN #__k2_items i ON tags_xref.itemID = i.id";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN #__k2_categories c ON c.id = i.catid";
$query .= " WHERE t.published=1";
$query .= " AND i.published=1 ";
$query .= " AND ( i.publish_up = ".$db->Quote($nullDate)." OR i.publish_up <= ".$db->Quote($now)." ) ";
$query .= " AND ( i.publish_down = ".$db->Quote($nullDate)." OR i.publish_down >= ".$db->Quote($now)." )";
$query .= " AND i.trash=0 ";
$query .= " AND i.access <= {$aid}";
$query .= " AND c.published=1 ";
$query .= " AND c.trash=0 ";
$query .= " AND c.access <= {$aid}";
```

Comment: _it does not show anything_ Meaning what? A verifiably empty result set, or nothing on the page ( PHP white screen) ?

Comment: Debugging is in order `echo $query;` and run the query as it is defined in that string.

Comment: does the query work at all without the order by clause appended at the end?

Comment: It shows nothing as result, how ever Im pretty sure that there are values to show. If I do not add the line "order by" shows results, when I add the line "order by" does not show anything

Comment: hmmm that is interesting... I would take a look at this bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70466 and the related SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19088608/1707323 and see if it is similiar to your case.

Comment: change `ORDER BY t.id DESC` to `ORDER BY RAND()` just for a test to see if any order by clause stops the query or if it is just your specific order by. I am still interested to see the echoed query to make sure that you add the order by clause at the right location and to check table name.

Comment: This is the echo result: http://pastebin.com/Q0xeqBmU
If I use RAND does not show anything

Comment: Please provide the full code being used, including calling the database class. Also read the joomla documentation as your query is using old coding standards

Comment: OK... this is past what I know... probably a Joomla error... which I have no experience with.

Comment: @Lodder here is a sample of the code: http://pastebin.com/eEDyNV8C

Answer (score 1):

The hash symbol denotes a comment in php and also MySQL. If #__k2_tags is really your table name which for your sake I hope it is not then you need to put backticks ` around it like

```
$query = "SELECT t.name, t.id FROM `#__k2_tags` as t";
```

**Reference:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Making your query end up looking like the following to MySQL which is an invalid bad syntax query.

```
$query = "
SELECT t.name, t.id FROM
 LEFT JOIN
 LEFT JOIN
 LEFT JOIN
 WHERE t.published=1
 AND i.published=1 
 AND ( i.publish_up = ".$db->Quote($nullDate)." OR i.publish_up <= ".$db->Quote($now)." ) 
 AND ( i.publish_down = ".$db->Quote($nullDate)." OR i.publish_down >= ".$db->Quote($now)." )
 AND i.trash=0 
 AND i.access <= {$aid}
 AND c.published=1 
 AND c.trash=0 
 AND c.access <= {$aid}"
```

Comment: Im using Joomla, I think # symbol is a shortcut

Comment: then why is this not tagged joomla??

Comment: as Michael Berkowski commented, echoing out the query variable would show if Joomla replaced the table prefix I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8132757/1707323 which helped me understand the `#__` but this answer is still noteworthy

Comment: @israhes can you echo out the query to display and post edit it into the question to see if Joomla is actually replacing the table prefixes like it should be... In other words. Your echo should have something different instead of `#__`. If your echo shows `#__` then your problem is Joomla somewhere which I know very little about. I stick to basic PHP and don't use Joomla

Comment: `#__` is the prefix used for joomla database tables.

Comment: If you are using Joomla why are you not using the real Joomla API for building queries? Also it is better form to use $db->quote.  Assuming you've used the API to define $query you can do echo $query->dump(); to see the query and then go run it directly in phpmyadmin or whatever you use.  In a complex query I would get the query right first, then work on putting it into the api.